# Network device driver

Tags: network-programming, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to write Linux device driver for network based device. This network device is just Input output control only and also this device connects through Ethernet port via ethernet cable. How can i write driver? How to transfer data between device and kernel?

Comment: Google it for "How to write Ethernet Device Driver"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the device just connects to the Linux machine through Ethernet, then you don't need to write a kernel driver at all - a userspace daemon can have full access to Ethernet through the `AF_PACKET` socket address family.  See the [`packet(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html) man page for details.

Comment: thanks for you response. But i want write driver accesses via application.

Comment: Whatever you want to access from  the ethernet driver can access through the socket calls. Just emphasize on "Socket Programming".

Comment: Trying to write a driver for hardware like this in-kernel is trying to put a square peg in a round hole.  But if you insist, you can just kick off a kernel thread that uses an `AF_PACKET` socket to talk to the hardware.

Comment: @jhonnash - can you also point out what is the ipaddress and port number he should specify while creating a socket ?

Comment: @AbhishekSagar - It depends because either you want to write your application for single client-server or 1 server and multiple client via broadcasting method. According to your communication model you have to choose IP addresses.

Answer (score -1):

You can choose for a TCP or UDP connection communication.

for TCP you must opt for a stream based transfer
But UDP is not a reliable communication rather it is faster as compared to TCP.

I would suggest to go with *Beginning Linux Programming* which has a theoretical as well as a practical reflection.

Cheers !!